# Django cannot show login error on the page

Tags: python, django

I am making a login page and testing it. I try to enter the wrong password and hope it can show the error message. But it seems not, it just refreshes the page, how can I show the message error? Here is my code:
login.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Login</h1>

        <form method="POST" action="">
            {% csrf_token%}
            {% for field in form %}
            {{ field.label }}
            {{ field }}
            
            {{ field.help_text }}
            {{ field.errors }}
            <br></br>
            {% endfor %}
            <input type="submit" name="LoginUser">
            <a class="button" href="{% url 'home' %}"> Cancel </a>
        </form> 

        {% for message in messages %}
            <p id='message'>{{ message }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
        <h3>Don't have an account? <a href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a> </h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

view.py:

```
class register(FormView):
    template_name = "showList/register.html";
    form_class = CreateUserForm;
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save();
        messages.success(self.request, "User had been created.");
        return redirect('login');
    

class LoginPage(FormView):
    template_name = "showList/login.html";
    form_class = AuthenticationForm;

    def form_valid(self, form):
        username = form.cleaned_data['username'];
        password = form.cleaned_data['password'];
        user = authenticate(username = username, password = password);
        print(user)
        if user is not None:
            login(self.request, user);
            return redirect('home');
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Form.errors`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors) is a dictionary, which means you have to iterate over its items. Try doing something like this:

```
{% if form.errors %}
<div class="text-center">
    {% for _, error in form.errors.items %}
    <strong>{{ error }}</strong>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

change `{{ field.errors }}` to

```
{% for error in field.errors %}
    {{ error }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In views:

```
from django.contrib import messages
```

Your html:

```
{% for message in messages %}
  <p class="{{ message.tags }}">{{ message }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to show success or error

```
if success:
    messages.success
else:
    messages.error
```